# Can't show image generated by GStreamer using QML Image

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, qt5.5

I'm using `GStreamer` to generate the `jpg` files which does work as expected on Linux dev machine and on Windows desktop. But my Qt application throws this error

`QML Image: Invalid image data: file:///home/camera/capture_0.jpg`

I'm using `camerabin` of `GStreamer` and using this `image-capture-caps`.

```
GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_new_full (gst_structure_new ("video/x-raw",
    "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "YUY2", "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1280, "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1024, NULL), NULL);
g_object_set (m_cameraBin, "image-capture-caps", caps, NULL);
gst_caps_unref (caps);
```

I've tried different `format`s like `RGB` which didn't work either.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Other tools can read the jpg files? Are they jpg or png? In the first sentence you say “jpg” but then the file extension is “png”?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld My bad, that was a typo. Infact, I've tried both `jpg` and `png` as well. Updated my post. Thanks.